# How do I programmatically open an external folder in Android?

Tags: android

My app downloads an epub file to /external/downloads/{MyFolder}/. I can normally auto-open the file in an e-reader like Play Books. As a fall back, however, in case of no installed e-reader, I want to open the device's default File Browser to MyFolder. On my device, that browser program is called "My Files".

I'm getting an `ActivityNotFoundException`. How do I programmatically open that File Browser? Ideally to the {MyFolder} location.

```
try {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    File file = new File(fileUri.getPath());
    File folder = new File(file.getParent());
    Uri folderUri = Uri.fromFile(folder);
    intent.setDataAndType(folderUri, "resource/folder");
    getContext().startActivity(intent);
} catch (Exception e1) {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Ebook saving to " + fileUri.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

For the record, `fileUri.toString()` for the epub file is "content://media/external/downloads/16143".

`.startActivity(intent)` throws the exception:

> No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.{mydomain}.app.provider/root/external/downloads typ=resource/folder flg=0x1 }

I've also attempted to change `folderUri` declaration to the following, and get similar errors.

```
final ContentValues v = new ContentValues();
v.put(MediaStore.Downloads.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/{MyFolder}/");
final ContentResolver r = getContext().getContentResolver();
Uri folderUri = r.insert(MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, v);
```

My AndroidManifest.xml has

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.{mydomain}.app.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">

    <!-- resource file to create -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>
```

And my file_paths.xml has

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external" path="." />
    <external-files-path name="external_files" path="." />
    <root-path name="root" path="." />
</paths>
```

I've also attempted with the paths being "./", and with no root-path element, and it makes no difference.

Comment: fileUri.getPath() is no file system path and cannot be used for the File class as you have seen.

Comment: What is the value of folderUri.toString()?

Comment: First try to start that file manager without specifying any uri.

Comment: @blackapps I've previously attempted to use what I thought was the real path: "/external/downloads/{MyFolder}", but that didn't work either. Would that be the correct system path, to use, though? Should I be able to do folderUri = Uri.fromFile(new File("/external/downloads/{MyFolder}"))?

Comment: Repeat: `First try to start that file manager without specifying any uri.`.

Comment: @blackapps how? The File class does not have a parameterless constructor. It requires either parent/child, or pathname (String), or java.net.URI (not to be confused with android.net.Uri).

Comment: I did not mention a File class. I asked you to just start the file manager.

Answer (score 1):

If you want directly browse the Camera folder in public DCIM folder with the Files app:

```
String scheme = "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ADCIM%2FCamera";

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(scheme), "vnd.android.document/root"); 

startActivity(intent );
```

I assume you can easily change that for Download/MyFolder.

I think this only works for Android 11+ devices. Please try out.